# Resetting my textboxes does not work all the time. How to fix?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I am using asp.net 3.5 (codebehind c#). My users are running IE 7 or 8. I have a data entry page with several `TextBox`es.

When I want to clear the all the `TextBox`es, I do a sever.transfer back to the same page.

**Maybe 99% of the time, this clears the `TextBox`es. Every so often it does not.**

I know that a roundtrip to the server has happened because:

- The dropdown lists and radiobuttonlists on the page get reset, and
- DB processing happened as shown by a record having been saved to the
  DB.

The inconsistency is confusing me.

What could be causing the `TextBox`es to persist data in this way and how can I prevent it from ever happening?

It is resulting in users saving the same data twice.

I don't think this would have anything to do with it, but there are also various js functions on the page for validation, capitalizing the first letter of an input, etc

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this behavior on "clean" IE installations, i.e. installations where people don't have any add-in's.  There are add-ins that "save" your form data to help save time refilling forms.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this behavior at all. That is the problem. However, I will check the machines that are being used to see if they have any add ins. Can you suggest some add ins to look for? Even if there are addins, why would they only cuse this to happen about 1% of the time?

Comment: The one that I personally use is LastPass, https://lastpass.com

Comment: Even if there are addins, why would they only cause this to happen about 1% of the time?

Comment: Well I guess that's the next question, if you find users with addins like this, are they able to reproduce it consistently.  It's all part of troubleshooting, I'm just trying to offer ideas that you can look at.  In the end, this is most likey a browser issue and has absolutely nothing to do with your code, unless your code is refilling the TB's from a cookie or view state or something.

Comment: Why are you doing a Server.Transfer? You should probably do a Response.Redirect instead.

Comment: @kevin - One less page call with Server.Transfer?

Comment: @LillLansey You might want to read the answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/a/4862741/1191903 that explains what Server.Transfer does vs Response.Redirect - I would guess this is the cause of your issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this [MSDN article describes the Server.Transfer method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525800%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), this is probably not the right way to empty the `TextBox`es. The method explicitly keeps all state information.

A better approach is described within [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10880887/79485https://stackoverflow.com/a/10880887/79485https://stackoverflow.com/a/10880887/79485):

```
foreach (var item in Page.Controls)
        {
            if (item is TextBox)
            {
                ((TextBox)item).Text = "";
            }
        }
```

You will keep the roundtrips to just one, and you could keep all other user inputs as they were, if you like.